# Octree frustum culling vs Linear culling?

Tags: game-engine, directx-12

I want to integrate frustum culling into my little engine.so i implemented culling using two algorithm as title.One of algorithm is linear culling.

for(i in all objects)
     test(i);

and other one is octree with a recusively intersection detection.

```
Linear: 10 ms stable time. (1000000 objects)


Octree: 40-90ms (of course if set the frustum to a un-intersection state with minmum octree depth,there is no time wasting.
```

I'm confusing how to trade off two algorithms.

Comment: Without any knowledge specific to this problem, I would say brute force cache-friendly memory access and simplicity wins out over something more sophisticated. This works until the amount of objects gets too large.

Comment: Yeah.you are right.Some old way like octree is not suitable on modern cpu under frustum culling.But I guess collission would got a high performance,not like frustum culling invoved with more collision detection.